# Should I see ads when I'm logged in?

Tags: discussion, login, advertising

I can't remember this -- when I'm logged in to any Stack Exchange site, I should see *fewer* ads than a not-logged-in user or should I see *none* of them?

Anyway, I've been using SE for two years or more now and today is the first day, ever, that I have seen an ad on any SE site while being logged in:

[image: screen shot]

Is this a bug or by-design and I was just so extremely lucky to not run into this situation ever before?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have less than 200 rep on the site, therefore you will see ads.

[Reduced ads privilege level](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads)

However, not all sites have ads. Beta sites don't and even most graduated sites don't. The site has to be generating enough traffic for ads to be worthwhile. The Apple site must have just passed that threshold if you've only just started seeing ads.